# preg_match with diacritic letters also?

Tags: php, preg-match

Basically what I need is to check whether the string contains ONLY letters `a-zA-Z` but also all `a-zA-Z` but with diacritics such as `ž,č,š,ľ...`also the long ones `ó,ý,á,í` and so on...
I have no idea how to do so...

This is the only code for matching characters I know...

```
preg_match('/[^a-z\s-]/i',$string)
```

Any help much appreciated.

**PS: I don't want any other characters such as $,€,%,!,.,, etc...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unicode properties:

```
preg_match('/[^\pL\s-]/u', $string)
```

`\pL` stands for any letter in any language
`u` is a modifier for unicode character
`i` modifier is not needed here because `\pL` is for upper and lower case letters